# How to create In app community for users in mobile application

Tags: android, ios

We are new to pet based business and planning to release both IOS and Android mobile application . We would like to enhance our application with feature to create In App community building .

We need that our user should login to our application and join our community and view and provide details through community .

Also we are new to mobile application .

Please provide the suggestions is there any tool that we can use? Is there way to create community using Facebook or any other ?

Thanks,

Comment: you are asking how to build forum?

Comment: @Lu_. Yes . But is there any available framework that we can use in our mobile application. It would be like in app  community forumThanks.